# Computing and animating mesh deformations

Tags: mesh, geometry

I have two different meshes with the same topology, and I'd like to animate one deforming to the other.

I believe I need to somehow compute and apply the deformation between the meshes, and set the second mesh as a shape key of the first. Is such an operation feasible?

Comment: You probably want to look at the [blendercookie werewolf tutorial](http://cgcookie.com/blender/cgc-courses/creating-a-werewolf-in-blender/) for that.

Comment: @sambler maybe you must make an answer from your comment.

Comment: While I remembered the tutorial I forgot how simple the key point is...

Comment: What does it mean to have the same topology?

Comment: I may be using the term wrong.. what I'm trying to say is that `mesh_1 + deformation => mesh_2` - that the meshes have the same connectivity.

Comment: For example, try subdividing a cube until it's got the same number of vertices as a Suzanne, then set it as a Suzanne's shape key as in sambler's answer. The result is not a continuous deformation from a monkey to a cube; I'd say that Suzanne and the subdivided cube have different topology.

Comment: It'd be great if someone could confirm or correct the usage of the word!

Comment: @ajwood I decided to [ask that question](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2127/what-defines-matching-topology) - My guess is that it is the order that the vertices are stored and connected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Having two meshes with the same topology (The meshes must have the same number of vertices for this to work) you can easily use one mesh to define a shape key of the second mesh.

First select the mesh that you wish to be the shape key, then shift-select the target mesh. In the mesh properties click the little down arrow next to the Shape Keys list and select 'Join as Shapes'

[image]

You can have multiple meshes that each get applied as shape keys in the one step, each separate object will create it's own shape key.

You may also wish to copy a shape key from one object to another with the Transfer Shape Key.

Comment: Brilliant! Everything is so simple, once you know how to do it :P