# How to transfer a shape key between different meshes?

Tags: modeling, mesh, objects, shape-keys

As the title says how would I go about transferring a shape key between two different meshes? The meshes I am using have a similar shape and topology (esp. with area that is affected by the shape key) but different vertex count.

I am aware of the "Transfer Shape Key" function but that requires a mesh with an exact number of vertices and I don't think simply matching the vertex count will work out right (like random verts flying off to oblivion when using that shape key).

Comment: [This explains matching geometry](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/2145/935)