# UV coordinates on a deformed plane

Tags: uv

I added a plane to a scene, subdivided it, and deformed it with proportional editing:

[image]

I'd like to UV unwrap this plane, making the mapping *what the would have been without the edit mode deformations*. In other words, I'd like my UV map to look like a square grid.

Is it possible to UV map this deformed plane to a square grid? Or do I need to start from scratch, and make sure I unwrap it before I do the edits?

Comment: I find myself in this situation quite often.  I don't know of any way other than doing a normal U > *unwrap* and then a whole bunch of S > X > 0/S > Y > 0 to align the rows/columns of vertices into a grid.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One easy way to do this is to add another plane, subdivide it the same number of times, and UV unwrap as desired. You can now in *Object Mode* select first the deformed plane, then the new one. Now press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> and select *Transfer UV Maps*. Any edits to the UV of the first will be visible on the deformed plane as well, as the exact same data is used.

[image]

Comment: Awesome! The selection order should be the other way around though; the new plane needs to be the active object.

Comment: Really great and useful method @NoviceInDisguise. It openes new possibilities for me. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 9):

It is simple to unwrap a deformed plane like in your image, back to a square UV map.

In face select mode, select all the faces with <kbd>A</kbd> and make one of the faces [active](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/21050/2217).
Then press <kbd>U</kbd> > *Follow Active Quads* and then choose *Even* and press OK.

This will give you a even square UV layout.

Comment: This didn't work for me: http://imgur.com/hcRCqLI

Comment: @ajwood is the objects scale set to 1? Did you use the *Even* method of Follow Active Quads?

Comment: Yep, followed exactly...

Comment: @ajwood Try resetting the uvs first with `U` > *Reset* then unwrapping with Follow Active Quads.

Comment: That did it! After the _Reset_ the Follow Active Quads created square grid, although it was scaled up. Pretty simple to scale it down to size though. Thanks!

Comment: `Report: Error - No active face`

Comment: @Keavon you do not have a active face. When selecteing all the faces with `A`, there will be no active face. See if [this](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/27710/2217) answer helps you.

Answer (score 3):

What if you unwrap a square mesh, a flat one, with same number of polygons. Copy that UV, and paste it into the deform mesh you want? 
There is an addon to copy UV between objects I think.

Comment: You can copy UVs with Ctrl L. However it requires not only matching vertex counts, but matching vertex *order*. There is no guarantee you'll be able to create another grid plane with identical vertex order.. See http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/2127/599