# UV mapping a straight image around a ring shaped flat mesh

Tags: mesh, uv

Is it possible to mapping a image around a ring shaped mesh? I would imagine there should be a way to curve/distort the image around the mesh. If not, how can I straighten out the mesh easily instead to fit the image?

[image: mesh ring and texture]

Comment: select_all, then select one face, then press U, select follow active quad

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using face select, select all the faces of the circle then have one face the active face (selected last, it will be lighter orange).

Press <kbd>U</kbd> > *Follow Active Quads*, then hit OK.

That will give you a straight line of the  UV for the circular faces, which will deform your pattern around the edge perfectly.
[image: animated gif]