# Straighten UV map edges?

Tags: uv, workflow

Is there a way to straighten all the edges of the selected area of a UV map automatically? This means aligning every edge (set of consecutive vertices selectable by <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>RMB</kbd>). Currently I have to do this manually, as illustrated below, by selecting an edge (<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>RMB</kbd> over the edge), hitting <kbd>S</kbd> to scale, and <kbd>X</kbd> or <kbd>Y</kbd> to constrain it to the X or Y axis and then <kbd>0</kbd> to set the scale to zero, averaging the distance between all points on that axis.

[image: Animation showing the process of manually straightening UV edges]

This is the final result that I'm trying to achieve:

[image: Final unwrapping with all edges aligned along the X and Y axes]

As illustrated above, this is extremely slow to do manually. I have tried Follow Active Quads, but in most cases that doesn't result in a straight grid where all the vertices are lined up along the X and Y axes. Is there an automatic way to straighten the edges of a UV map by lining them up along the X and Y axes?

Comment: there is W key for straightening one edge at a time , or use follow quad when unwrapping to give you a straight grid

Comment: You can faster this process using SHIFT+R shortcut. Align a single edge scaling it along x, y or z axis and pressing 0. Then select the next edge, press SHIFT+R and your previous action will be repeated. You may also check out this add-on: http://cgcookiemarkets.com/blender/all-products/uv-squares/ It's a great tool for doing things like this.

Comment: Your best bet might be to just unwrap the mesh again using a method that preserves the proportions of the mesh (Project from View, Follow Active Quads, etc)

Comment: @Gonzou Shift + R sounds quite helpful. I'll be sure to remember that. That add-on you linked to looks perfect, but could somebody here write a similar one for free use by the Blender Stack Overflow community?

Comment: Set all your reputation as a bounty and maybe someone may do an add-on like this for you ;). But seriously, you may also check out the NoviceInDisguise's answer here: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23293/uv-coordinates-on-a-deformed-plane May be helpful for U.

Comment: @Gonzou I may put a bounty on it, but just to make sure it doesn't go to waste if nobody answers, I should ask if anyone may be interested in writing such an add-on if I were to put a bounty on it.

Comment: Note that follow quads won't necessarily unwrap in a rectangle shape.