# UVs should stretch texture

Tags: mesh

I would like to create a fence that is "buckled" (sorry, I don't know the correct translation). The fence should be affected a lot by gravity. 
If anybody knows how to explain that better, please tell me!

This is a picture:
[image: old fence]

I thought I would do this with a plane. I thought I should subdivide it and move the vertices around so that the textures will be stretched and shrunken in order to give create such a worn-out fence.

My approach looks like this:
[image: plane as a fence]

However, when I put a texture onto my model in Unity3D, the texture is absolutely fine, but that is not what I wanted. :-) I wanted the texture to be uneven.

Can somebody tell me how I can achieve that? 
Thank you!

Comment: Before deforming the mesh, UV unwrap and assign the texture.  Deform the mesh afterwards and the texture will deform with it.

Comment: Related question: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23293/uv-coordinates-on-a-deformed-plane

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unwrap your mesh before deforming it will result in a good mapping.
[image]
Then when deforming the mesh, the texture will follow.
[image]

Comment: Do you know if there is a feature that would allow me to simply paint in distortions in Blender of the kind that I have introduced?

Comment: you can sculpt or use a cloth sim