# How can I make a rectangular UV map for a section of a sphere?

Tags: uv-image-editor

I have a section of a sphere representing earth. I also have a rectangular image of the surface of that section, in an equirectangular projection. I would like to place this on the section of the sphere as if it was a simple rectangle, as if it were a plane that was curved.

The sphere has lines of latitude and longitude from the sphere, rather than subdivided squares, so creating a plane and copying the UV from that does not seem to work.

This is the post that comes closest to working, however it creates a trapezoidal shape.

[UV coordinates on a deformed plane](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/23293/uv-coordinates-on-a-deformed-plane)

[image: UV project results]

Comment: u->reset a single face to turn it into a big rectangle, then ctrl-l selected link in 3D editor to select all while retaining the same active face, then u->follow active quads to a make a bunch of joined rectangles, finally ctrl-p pack islands in UV editor to fit it into the UV space.

Comment: That worked, it was 90 degrees off and half the width which was easy to fix. Your response is showing as a comment other wise I would mark it as solved.

Comment: It's basically in one of the answers to your linked question.  You have to read the comments a bit for some troubleshooting.